# Sharing state between processes for multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

There is this [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) for sharing state between processes, but it doesn't completely answer my question.  I have the following code

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Array

#This is my function
def my_func(my_array):
    my_array = ["hello", "hi", "howdy"]

# I am initiating an array called arr that has string elements here
if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr = Array('c')

    p = Process(target=my_func, args=(arr))
    p.start()
    p.join()

    print(arr[:])
```

I want arr to be equal to `["hello", "hi", "howdy"]` by the end, but my code does not work.  Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

This will not do. According to the [Array documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Array), allowed types [do not include strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#module-array).

Also `my_array` changes from being a pointer to the `Array` object to a pointer to the array of strings in `my_func`.

A more proper way that tackles both these problems would be:

```
def my_fun(my_array):
  my_array[:] = map(ord, ['a','b','c'])
```

[`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=ord#ord) maps a character to an integer